# How do I return data via Ajax using Plupload on Upload Complete?

Tags: php, jquery, plupload

I've been trying for the last few hours to get something... anything back from the pluploader upon completion of the queue to no avail.

Here is my JS code:

```
var uploader = $('#pluploadDiv').pluploadBootstrap();

uploader.bind("UploadComplete", function(up, files) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(response.response);
    alert(obj.result);

});
```

On the very last line of the upload.php script, I have:

```
die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : "'.$_REQUEST['unitID'].'", "id" : "id"}');
```

This makes sense to me... but it's not working, the files upload without problems, but the alert doesn't even fire off... there is no response whatsoever.

Thoughts?

**EDIT WITH NEW CODE AS A SOLUTION**

The JS that I'm using (thanks jbl):

```
var uploader = $('#pluploadDiv').pluploadBootstrap();

uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(upldr, file, object) {
    var myData;
    try {
        myData = eval(object.response);
    } catch(err) {
        myData = eval('(' + object.response + ')');
    }
    $("#vehicle_id_value").val(myData.result);
});
```

Upload.php script stayed the same, last line of code:

```
die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : "'.$_REQUEST['unitID'].'", "id" : "id"}');
```

So basically when I create the shell row to associate images to in the upload script, I pass the row ID back to the original form into a hidden input field via the FileUploaded event that is bound to the plupload object.

```
<input type="hidden" name="vehicle_id_value" id="vehicle_id_value" value="" />
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: If you need more code to answer, please let me know and I'll post more!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several files could have been uploaded as part of the upload process. The individuals responses are not avalaible anymore when on `UploadComplete` stage.
If you want to display info about a specific file upload, you should bind to the `FileUploaded` event instead of `UploadComplete`.
Something like :

```
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(upldr, file, object) {
    var myData;
    try {
        myData = eval(object.response);
    } catch(err) {
        myData = eval('(' + object.response + ')');
    }
    alert(myData.result);
});
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you - I will give this a shot, but I'm only looking for one piece of data at the end of submission on UploadComplete.  When the uploader script runs I'm inserting a record into the database to act as a shell so that I can associate these uploaded files with something.  I have the ID of this shell which needs to be passed back to my original form.  I'll use it to update the shell with the $_POST data in the original submission.  With this piece of data I can alter a hidden variable on the original page and have it passed in the $_POST. If you have any other insight, it's appreciated!

Comment: @TonyMancini are you trying to perform something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/14786842/1236044 ?

Comment: yes, I'm close to performing this without the additional ajax call though, and I'd prefer to continue on the path I'm on.  I just ran your code and got the response I was looking for - answer accepted, thanks for your help!!

Comment: Don't `eval` that! Run it through JSON.parse, instead. There's a polyfill available if you are unfortunate enough to have to support oldIE.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried echo instead of die?

```
echo '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : "'.$_REQUEST['unitID'].'", "id" : "id"}';
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fileupload(fileuploadid, urlashx, foldername, keyid, filelimit, filefilters) {
   $("#" + fileuploadid).plupload({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
        url: urlashx,

        //Set parameter for server side
        multipart_params: {
            foldername: foldername,
            keyid: keyid
        },

        // Maximum file size
        max_file_size: filelimit,

        // User can upload no more then 20 files in one go (sets multiple_queues to false)
        max_file_count: 20,
        multiple_queues: true,

        //chunk_size: '10mb',

        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize: {
            //width: 200,
            //height: 200,
            quality: 90,
            crop: false // crop to exact dimensions
        },

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: [
            { title: "Allowed files", extensions: filefilters }
        ],

        // Rename files by clicking on their titles
        rename: true,

        // Sort files
        sortable: true,

        // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
        dragdrop: true,

        // Views to activate
        views: {
            list: true,
            thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
            active: 'thumbs'
        },

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: 'plupload/js/Moxie.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: 'plupload/js/Moxie.xap',

        // Post init events, bound after the internal events
       init: {

            FileUploaded: function (up, file, jsonMsg) {
                var json = JSON.parse(jsonMsg.response); // now I have json object 
                if (json.success) {
                    AlertMessage("Message", json.message, "success", "False");

                } else {
                    AlertMessage("Message", json.message, "error", "False");
                }
                up.splice(); //remove items of container
                up.refresh(); //refresh container
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, res) {
  var res1 = res.response.replace('"{', '{').replace('}"', '}');
  var objResponse = JSON.parse(res1);
  alert(objResponse.fn);
});
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can add an explanation to the answer you provided.