# Echoing value using AJAX for plupload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, plupload

Hi This is my JS file for plupload

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
browse_button : 'pickfiles', // you can pass in id...
container: document.getElementById('container'), // ... or DOM Element itself
url : '../../assets/php/upload.php',
flash_swf_url : '../js/Moxie.swf',
silverlight_xap_url : '../js/Moxie.xap',

filters : {
    max_file_size : '10mb',
    mime_types: [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
        {title : "Video files", extensions : "mp4"}
    ]
},

init: {
    PostInit: function() {
        document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';

        document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
            uploader.start();
            return false;
        };
    },

    FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
        plupload.each(files, function(file) {
            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div>';
        });
    },

    UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
        document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
    },

    Error: function(up, err) {
        document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
    }
}
});

uploader.init();
```

In my upload.php I return an

```
echo $name
```

I would like my plupload to display the $name on upload complete.

I have tried this solution 
[How do I return data via Ajax using Plupload on Upload Complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555550/how-do-i-return-data-via-ajax-using-plupload-on-upload-complete)

```
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(upldr, file, object) {
var myData;
try {
    myData = eval(object.response);
} catch(err) {
    myData = eval('(' + object.response + ')');
}
alert(myData.result);
```

But when I add it to my code it keeps returning "Your browse does not support HTML5,Flash,silverlight,html4"

If I take out the Fileuploaded method it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Worked it out.  Should go like this.

```
UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
        document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
    },
            FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
            // Called when a file has finished uploading
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "#" + info.response + ": ";
           var myData;
               try {
    myData = eval(info.response);
} catch(err) {
    myData = eval('(' + info.response + ')');
}
$("#video_id").val(info.result);
            },
    Error: function(up, err) {
        document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
    }
```